# Why doesn't OpenCV get installed on the base (root) environment of Anaconda?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

After installing **Anaconda**, at first, I installed tensorflow with conda, then I tried to install **opencv** with the following conda commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 opencv
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 opencv
```

But, none of the avobe worked, it failed to install **opencv** on my **base (root)** environment. (However, I became able to install it on a different environment.)

The error message I got is:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

I also tried to install **opencv** with **Anaconda Navigator** on **base (root)** environment. But, it didn't work also.

Then, I tried to install **opencv** with **pip** with the following commmand:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

But, it also didn't work.

Now, How can I install **opencv** on my **base (root)** environment?

Comment: Can you tell us the error it prints or what does it say when you enter these commands to install it ?

Comment: @MinaAbdEl-Massih Error: "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source."

Comment: @RAWNAKYAZDANI always add additional information by adding it to your question through the edit button Because a) you can then properly format the addition and b) someone reading your question does not need to read throug comments to get all relevant information

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have edited my description, please remove the downvote, if you have given it.

Comment: @RAWNAKYAZDANI thx, however, I was not the one that downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (partial) error message (from the comments):

> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

and the fact that you were able to install it into a different environment:

> However, I became able to install it on a different environment.

Indicate that you have conflicts with other packages in your base environment, i.e. `conda` was not able to determine how to fit `opencv` and its dependencies together with other packages in your base environment.

The best practice here would be to set up a new environment and only install the packages that you need for a certain project.

Alternatively, you could also uninstall anaconda and install miniconda (which is the same as aanconda, but without the preinstalled packages) and then install into `base` only what you need.